# 3 column fluid layout with center-aligned text

Tags: css

I'm trying to build the following layout in CSS but really struggling to work out how to do it. It's a simple 3 column layout but all columns can contain content that may change so they can't have a fixed width.

The problem comes in that the HEADING text in the middle column should always be centre aligned to the middle of the page (as seen in example A and B).

I also need it to wrap when the viewport width is too small to fit all the text on one line (example C).

Any ideas how to achieve this? I've created a simple codepen as a starting point if it helps: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXJqgM

[image: Layout]

```
CSS:
.centre-of-page {
  border-left:#333 1px dashed;
  height:100%;
  width:1px;
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:1px
}

.row {
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:sans-serif;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.col1 {
  background-color:green;
}

.col2 {
  background-color:yellow;
}

.col3 {
  background-color:teal;
}


HTML:
<div class="centre-of-page"></div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col1">Some flexible content</div>
  <div class="col2">This is the page heading</div>
  <div class="col3">Some really, really long content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] showing what you've tried so far please

Comment: ^ Updated the codepen

Comment: Your question needs a [mcve], don't ask us to visit a third party site to see it please. If codepen is down, goes away, or is blocked, then your question loses all value to future visitors.

Comment: Is the heading text centered to the viewport at all times? Even in image C?

Comment: @sol - Yeah, unfortunately!

Comment: @richwol But this might collide with the side columns if there's too much content.

Comment: Is this close? https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/YeXYqr

Comment: @Paul so if both the side columns had too much content then it'd just have to break onto 3 rows.

Comment: @sol, not quite.. the heading text isn't centre aligned to the centre of the page. Check the codepen / example I posted and you'll see it's got a dashed horizontal line showing where the centre of the viewport is.. the HEADING text should always be sat halfway across that

Comment: https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/YeXYqr ? It's not a very elegant solution -- Some issues with overlap that could be ironed out.

Comment: That's ridiculously close though! I'll have a look through how you've done it :)

Comment: Setting a `min-width` value for `.col-2` seems to work : https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/BYNJxM  -- but would need to be tested if content changes

Comment: That looks like it broke it at wider resolutions (3rd col drops to the next row). I'm wary about using percentages.. the heading will be in multiple languages so it could be quite a variety of widths!

Comment: In that case I don't think this solution will work for you...

Comment: No worries, thanks for trying anyway. It was VERY close!